# How to delete Solver(SOLVER.XLAM) code

Tags: excel, solver, vba

opening several examples of written macro's/ codes I suddenly get stuck with a code that seems to be secured. Solver (SOLVER.XLAM)
This is doiing noting and I would like to remove that from my system. I guess this is not a relavant code . Can anybody tell me what I should do? I already installed something to remove passwords but the SOLVER is still asking for passwords and I can not get rid of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solver is Excel add-in. If you want to remove it go to Excel Application > Options > Search for add-ins > Press something like 'go to' button > un-check Solver on the list (I can't give you exact path as I have Polish version of Excel).

It's better not to try to open Solver's VBA code as it is rather copyright protected.

Moreover, I don't think Solver makes any inconveniences when working with Excel or VBA.

Comment: Oh, that's why there is not so much info about deleting them . In that case I will only try to uncheck it like you suggested. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

verry nice, now it is not more active. For the one who want to deactivate this you should follow the next steps. For Excell 2010. Open Excell/go to options/ go to add ins/ go to active add ins on top of the page / select the SOLVER / press start (down the page)/ then a window will pop up so that you can uncheck or check it as you require. That was verry easy to do. Thank you Kaz for pointing me to the right direction! It is better to not delete them, maybe you will need them later